# Why keep brand guide and high quality logos private?

Tags: logo, branding, guides, style-guide

I was looking for (university) logos and brand guidelines on how to use them. I know for sure that they have both in high quality. But they quite often need an account to access them. Why? Why don't they allow anyone use these, and just make them publicly available? If I had a company, I would prefer people to use its logo in high quality and in accordance with the designer's vision.

I am not a designer (but a web developer), so I wasn't taught about any of this, but I have an interest in graphic design.

Comment: Why don't you ask them?  Perhaps they worry that criminals might use them to make fake student ID's or something like that. Who knows?!

Comment: It's usually  just random IT security policies and not really taking into account the context of the materials. For example, it's a huge pain to get stuff approved for 'public' consumption at my company so it's usually easier just to stick it out there behind a login of some sort.

Comment: When I am tasked with doing "ad books" for e.g. awards banquets, if the ad isn't provided as "camera-ready" by a pro, the logos provided are usually unusable. I usually manage to find a PDF brochure, press release or other public-facing asset that has a suitable vector logo that can be extracted or at least zoomed in to "full 1080p" which can then be captured and output as TIFF. The PDF will also often have the brand fonts list. Takes an extra five minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mostly this kind of stuff is on an intranet, for employees and students only. Things on the intranet are not necessarily put purposefully there behind a wall. It's just that people outside have very little use for this.

While it's true that the original designer has a some interest in keeping them out of public circulation, it's hard to know for sure if you can or cannot distribute the document freely outside of the organization. So it's just easier to keep it on the intranet.

You can probably access it by asking nicely.